# How to get the last word of a string?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which takes as an argument a file path

```
set filePath = %1
```

Now, lets say the file path is: `C:\Temp\Folder`, I want to set the `Folder` in a new variable. How can I do that?

I search on the web and all solutions are something like this:

```
for %%A in (%filePath%) do set last=%%A
```

but this works only for string with with spaces.

Comment: this may help: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.SplitString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract `Folder` from `C:\Temp\Folder` by applying the `~n` modifier to `%1`:

```
SET "last=%~n1"
```

If the last item may contain `.`, use `~nx` instead:

```
SET "last=%~nx1"
```

The `~n` modifier applies to a positional parameter or a loop variable and extracts the last name from the path specified by that parameter or variable. The `~x` modifier extracts the extension of the last name (the part starting from the last `.`). Accordingly, `~nx` extracts both the (last) name and the extension.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the slashes with a space, and then parse it out:

```
set filePath=%1
set filePath=%filePath:\= %
for %%A in (%filePath%) do set last=%%A
```

Comment: A neat trick, albeit brittle. If the name contains spaces, the result will be incorrect. Still, if the OP is only going to use this on names without spaces, this should do, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
for /F "tokens=4*" %%G IN (Data.txt) DO (
set value1=%%G
echo %value1%
)
```

**4*** is the number of the word that you want to take